# inserting php value into javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a countdown script i wan to key in the targetdate as a value in a form to store in the database.i have tried targetdate = $date in the script but it doesn't seems to read the value.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate ="1/31/2012 5:00 AM";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: where did you get that code sample from?

Comment: @greut: Why do you ask? (In any case, check out the actual [code](http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js) of `countdown.js`).

Comment: `language="JavaScript"` is deprecated in favor of `type="text/javascript"` since a long time… but oldies are hard to kill I guess ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var TargetDate = <?php echo json_encode($date); ?>;
</script>
```

Depending on the format of `$date` if it's a timestamp you could also try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var TargetDate = <?php echo json_encode(date('j/n/Y g:i a', $date)); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: My advice for this kind of situation you could use something like this: `<?=json_encode($date);?>` it's faster and more readable.

Comment: @khael: this is not so good syntax, <?= is considered a 'short tag' in php <= 5.4.0, so code with this depends on php configuration (on the other hand <?php echo ... ?> is always available).

Answer (score 0):

obviously you can't use it dinamycally as the json_encode will be parsed only before the onload javascript event , so if you need to modify it dinamically from server you should update it with ajax or getJson call